# In list of the Listings show without "Listing X:" part

Tags: pdftex, xetex, tcblisting

I have my Latex document that uses tcblistings.

I generate a list of the Listings with:

```
\begingroup
\parskip=0pt
\tcblistof[\chapter]{codes}{Listings}
\endgroup
```

Which result in the following Listings:
[image: Image of Listings]

I have tried to search on Stack Overflow and generally, however, I'm unable to find a way where the listing showed in the document is for example "Listing 1: Example of Python Code" but in the Listings list it should be "Example of Python Code" (as we already have the 1 in the side). All the changes I have tried results in me having both titles changed at the same time.

Does anyone know whether this is possible?

Comment: This would have really benefitted from a MWE.  Especially given your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly after posting this when looking through the tcblisting documentation I realised they have a parameter "list text", by adding

```
list text={#2}
```

to the list of config parameters when defining a list with \newtcblisting it solves this problem.